# Regex to exclude sub directory

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js

I'm going an automatic global registration. I'm struggling to figure how to exclude a specific sub directory. How would a regex for that look? I'm sorry to not have an example of a try but I have no idea honestly. Searching I found a few examples but it never matches to exclude just a directory.

This is how I get the components now.

```
const registerComponents = () => {
  const pascalCase = (name: string) => {
    return _.chain(name).camelCase().upperFirst().value()
  }

  const context = require.context('@/components', true, /\w+\.(vue)$/)
  _.forEach(context.keys(), fileName => {
    const componentConfig = context(fileName)

    const name = (fileName.split('/').pop() || '').replace(/\.\w+$/, '')
    const componentName = pascalCase(name)

    Vue.component(componentName, componentConfig.default || componentConfig)
  })
}
```

This is the structure. I would like to exclude the folder `/_exclude/`

```
components/_exclude/file.vue
components/_exclude/file2.vue
components/_exclude/svg/globe.vue
components/some-file.vue
components/svg/cart.vue
```

Comment: Maybe: `const context = require.context('@/components', true, /^(?!.*\/(?:_exclude)\/).*\w+\.(vue)$/)`

Answer (score 1):

This pattern would match all `.vue` files except those in `_exclude/`:

```
/^\.\/(?!_exclude\/).*\.vue$/
```

### [Breakdown](https://regex101.com/r/sZK7L6/1) of the pattern:

#### `^\.\/`

Match the leading `./` in the file paths returned from `require.context()`.

#### `(?!_exclude\/)`

Using [negative look-ahead](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#negative-lookahead), assert `_exclude/` does *not* match.

#### `.*`

Match any character(s). Note the `\w+` from your original pattern would have failed on file separators in the file paths.

#### `\.vue$`

Match the `.vue` file extension. Note the parentheses in `(vue)` from your original pattern would have created an unecessary capture group.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, easy:

```js
console.log( 'components/_exclude/file.vue'.replace(/\/_exclude\//,'/')  ); // <- RegEx
console.log( 'components/_exclude/file2.vue'.replace('/_exclude/','/') ); // <- String
console.log( 'components/_exclude/svg/globe.vue'.replace(/\/_exclude\//,'/') );
console.log( 'components/some-file.vue'.replace(/\/_exclude\//,'/') );
console.log( 'components/svg/cart.vue'.replace(/\/_exclude\//,'/') );

console.log( ' --- Or ---' );

console.log(
`components/_exclude/file.vue
components/_exclude/file2.vue
components/_exclude/svg/globe.vue
components/some-file.vue
components/svg/cart.vue`.replace(/\/_exclude\//g,'/') // <-- Using global flag (g) in case of more than one
);
```

Also for taking the component name, we can use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead:

```js
console.log( 'components/_exclude/file.vue'.match(/(?!\/)[^/]*?(?=(?:\.[^/.]+?)?(?:[?#].*)?$)/)[0] );
console.log( 'components/folder/file.vue?query=notme.ext'.match(/(?!\/)[^/]*?(?=(?:\.[^/.]+?)?(?:[?#].*)?$)/)[0] );
console.log( 'components/folder.name/file.vue'.match(/(?!\/)[^/]*?(?=(?:\.[^/.]+?)?(?:[?#].*)?$)/)[0] );
console.log( 'components/folder/file.min.vue'.match(/(?!\/)[^/]*?(?=(?:\.[^/.]+?)?(?:[?#].*)?$)/)[0] );
```

---

#### Update

General idea for take the `pathInfo` managed:

##### pathInfo function

```js
function pathInfo(s) {
    s=s.match(/(.*?\/)?(([^/]*?)(\.[^/.]+?)?)(?:[?#].*)?$/);
    return {folders:s[1],file:s[2],filename:s[3],fileext:s[4]};
}
var sample='folder/myfolder/excludeme/another/excludeme/onemore/file.min.js?query=1';
var result=pathInfo(sample);
console.log(result);
/*
{
  "folders": "folder/myfolder/excludeme/another/excludeme/onemore/",
  "file": "file.min.js",
  "filename": "file.min",
  "fileext": ".js"
}
*/
console.log(result.folders.split('/').filter(a=>a!='excludeme').join('/')+result.file);
// folder/myfolder/another/onemore/file.min.js
```

##### pathInfo (+Folders list) function

```js
function pathInfo(s) {
    s=s.match(/(.*?\/)?(([^/]*?)(\.[^/.]+?)?)(?:[?#].*)?$/);
    return {path:s[1],folders:s[1].split('/'),file:s[2],filename:s[3],fileext:s[4]};
}
var sample='folder/myfolder/excludeme/another/excludeme/onemore/file.min.js?query=1';
var result=pathInfo(sample);
console.log(result);
/*
{
  "path": "folder/myfolder/excludeme/another/excludeme/onemore/",
  "folders": [
    "folder",
    "myfolder",
    "excludeme",
    "another",
    "excludeme",
    "onemore",
    ""
  ],
  "file": "file.min.js",
  "filename": "file.min",
  "fileext": ".js"
}
*/
console.log(result.folders.filter(a=>a!='excludeme').join('/')+result.file);
// folder/myfolder/another/onemore/file.min.js
```

Comment: Most of this seems as "hacks", not really into doing a replace(), if I'm not using regex I'll use filter(). I'm also after Vue files and I would like to keep sub folders like "folder".

Comment: @Dejan.S non of these are "hacks". Same as while you use `.split('/')` it can be called as "hack" but it is a method. When your content is strings, we work with them with strings method. But if you need a well managed function something like [PHP `pathInfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) you can check the update. Please inform me if you need explanation about the Regex pattern.